# JQuery warn if click other button without saving edits

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple edit buttons in multiple rows, actually it was dynamically created as per database data, every line I have EDIT and DELETE button, when edit was clicked button will change to UPDATE and CANCEL, in my application I can edit multiple lines at one time, I want to get warning msg if click edit button without saving previous edits or without clicking cancel.

```
<div class="form view">
     <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-hover type-view-table">
                <thead>
                   <tr>
                   <th>Categories</th>
                   <th>Types</th>
                   <th></th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                     <?php
                      if(isset($_POST['table_product_view'])){
                      $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT id,category FROM '.$ps_detail_table_name, ARRAY_A);
                       foreach ($result as $value){   ?>
                        <tr id='catgry-row<?php echo $value['id']; ?>'>
                        <td id='catgry-name<?php echo $value['id']; ?>'><?php echo $value['category']; ?></td>
                        <td><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='edit-catgry<?php echo $value['id']; ?>' onclick=edit_category('<?php echo $value['id']; ?>');>Edit</button>
                            <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='delete-catgry<?php echo $value['id']; ?>' onclick=delete_category('<?php echo $value['id']; ?>');>Delete</button>
                            <button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' style='display:none' id='update-catgry<?php echo $value['id']; ?>' onclick=update_category('<?php echo $value['id']; ?>');>Update</button>
                            <button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' style='display:none' id='cancel-update-catgry<?php echo $value['id']; ?>' onclick=cancel_update_category('<?php echo $value['id']; ?>');>Cancel</button>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                <tbody id="table-type-view">
                </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
function edit_category(id) {
curent_edit_name = 'category';
curent_edit_id = id;
var catgry = document.getElementById("catgry-name"+id).innerHTML;

document.getElementById("catgry-name"+id).innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='catgry-new-name"+id+"' class='table-form-txt' value='"+catgry+"'>" +
    "<input type='hidden' id='catgry-hdn-name"+id+"' value='"+catgry+"'/>";
document.getElementById("edit-catgry"+id).style.display="none";
document.getElementById("delete-catgry"+id).style.display="none";
document.getElementById("update-catgry"+id).style.display="inline";
document.getElementById("cancel-update-catgry"+id).style.display="inline";
}

function update_category(id){
var new_valu = document.getElementById("catgry-new-name"+id).value;
var old_name = document.getElementById("catgry-hdn-name"+id).value;
$.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:ajaxurl,
        data:{'action':'php_for_ajax_callback',
             'old_ctgry_name':old_name,
              'new_ctgry_name':new_valu
        },
        success:function (response) {
            if(response=="success"){
                document.getElementById("catgry-name"+id).innerHTML=new_valu;
                document.getElementById("edit-catgry"+id).style.display="inline";
                document.getElementById("delete-catgry"+id).style.display="inline";
                document.getElementById("update-catgry"+id).style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("cancel-update-catgry"+id).style.display="none";
            }
        }

});
}


function cancel_update_category(id) {
 var catgry = document.getElementById("catgry-hdn-name"+id).value;

 document.getElementById("catgry-name"+id).innerHTML=catgry;
 document.getElementById("edit-catgry"+id).style.display="inline";
 document.getElementById("delete-catgry"+id).style.display="inline";
 document.getElementById("update-catgry"+id).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("cancel-update-catgry"+id).style.display="none";
 curent_edit_name = '';
 curent_edit_id = '';
 }
```

my table looks like this --http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/demo/demo_add-edit-and-delete-rows-from-table-dynamically-using-javascript.php

how to get a warning using Jquery oy Javascript

Comment: How about you include your code and show us what you have tried so far yourself?

Comment: wait ill update

Comment: ya I updated my code

Comment: where is your menu click event?

Comment: just tell me same thing while clicking other edit buttons, ill do it for menu and i have many other buttons also

Comment: simple way to do, define a global flag for edit and set it to 1, if flag is 0 and if flag is 1 then alert some message

Comment: agree with @Ankit +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this I have done with jQuery,
You may want to try like this:

```js
var edit_clicks = 0;
$( function(){
    $('button[id^=edit-catgry]').on('click', function(){
        if( edit_clicks > 0 ) {
            alert( "Update Or Cancel Previous row")
        }
        else {
            ++edit_clicks;
            $(this).css('display','none');
            $(this).siblings('button[id^=update-catgry-]').css('display','inline');
         $(this).siblings('button[id^=cancel-update-catgry]').css('display','inline');
        }
    });
  
    $('button[id^=cancel-update-catgry]').on('click', function(){
        --edit_clicks;
        $(this).siblings('button[id^=edit-catgry]').css('display','inline');
        $(this).siblings('button[id^=update-catgry-]').css('display','none');
     $(this).css('display','none');
    });
  
    $('button[id^=update-catgry]').on('click', function(){
        --edit_clicks;
        $(this).siblings('button[id^=edit-catgry]').css('display','inline');
        $(this).siblings('button[id^=cancel-update-catgry-]').css('display','none');
     $(this).css('display','none');
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='edit-catgry-1' onclick=edit_category(1);>Edit</button>
 <button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' style='display:none' id='update-catgry-1' onclick=update_category(1);>Update</button>
<button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' style='display:none' id='cancel-update-catgry-1' onclick=cancel_update_category(1);>Cancel</button>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='edit-catgry-2' onclick=edit_category(2);>Edit</button>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' style='display:none' id='update-catgry-2' onclick=update_category(2);>Update</button>
<button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' style='display:none' id='cancel-update-catgry-2' onclick=cancel_update_category(2);>Cancel</button>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='edit-catgry-3' onclick=edit_category(3);>Edit</button>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' style='display:none' id='update-catgry-3' onclick=update_category(3);>Update</button>
<button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' style='display:none' id='cancel-update-catgry-3' onclick=cancel_update_category(3);>Cancel</button>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

add [jquery listeners.](http://api.jquery.com/on/) this way you can control when an element is clicked and show the warning you want when an user make some action, you can use this listener for many events.